# How to identify the Neighbours of a Visio-Shape in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visio, office-addins

I am trying to implement a token game for BPMN processes in Microsoft Visio. As I am able to get all the drawed shapes, I want to identify the neighbours of a shape, in order to find out which shape comes next in the process.
That is my current idea for this token game.

However I am struggling with the documentation for these Visio-Shapes.

Does anybody know how to find out the next shape in such a process?

Answer (score 2):

Try use SpatialNeighbors property - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff767509.aspx
Hope that article also can help 
http://mikeborozdin.com/post/analysing-parent-child-relations-in-visio/

Comment: @ Surrogate  I tried it with SpatialNeighbours but it seems that i get different outputs depending on the type of the shape i want to identify neighbours of. For example: if my current Shape is an BPMN-Sequence Flow i get 2 of 2 existing neighbours. But if my current shape is a BPMN-Task i only get 1 of 2 existing neighbours.   Here is what i have done so far: `Selection neighbourShapes= currentShape.SpatialNeighbors[(short) VisSpatialRelationCodes.visSpatialTouching, 0,(short) VisSpatialRelationFlags.visSpatialFrontToBack];`